# Google Admin Activity API recurring calendar events

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-admin-sdk

If I create recurring calendar event (let's say 5pm-6pm Mon-Fri), will I be able to see this event in `Admin.activities.list` daily? or will I only see just for once, on the day I created it?

Answer (score 0):

The Activities.list will report only the actions performed to the items. So you will see the activity when the event was created. Or if the event is modified then you will see that in the response too. But you won't see a daily activity for this event.